# how to deploy azure webapp such that node modules get installed

Tags: node.js, azure-cli, azure-webapps

I am deploying a node webapp via the Azure CLI from my local source folder. I'm trying to understand how to get the node modules to get deployed. I can log into the deployed webapp, see the missing node_modules folder, and install them manually via this process:

browse: https://{app_name}.scm.azurewebsites.net/ > click: Bash > cd site/wwwroot > note there is no node_modules folder, despite there being package-lock.json and package.json! > npm ci > restart webapp

But the question is how to do this automatically from the deploy process. I am using 'az webapp up' from my local source folder to upload the webapp. It has a package-lock.json and a package.json as below:

```
{
  ...
  "main": "index.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "socket.io": "~2.3.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node index.js"
  }
}
```

Comment: I have a workaround, but would still like an answer as to how to pull the node modules post-deployment. In the meantime, I am able to zip my app (including the node_modules folder) and upload via [az webapp deployment source config-zip](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/deploy-zip). It's a good thing, too, because the manual workaround is far from reliable. I've found getting access to the console via ssh or bash works only occasionally  - often, it won't connect or will open but won't let you type.

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to deploy the web app with `node_modules` you can choose.

1. [Zip Deploy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-sg/azure/app-service/deploy-zip)
2. [FTP Deploy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-sg/azure/app-service/deploy-ftp)
3. Drag the project files to wwwroot in kudu
4. [Deploy through Git Action or DevOps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-sg/azure/app-service/deploy-continuous-deployment)
5. Deploy from VS Code

**...**( `az webapp up` is not a broad approach for deployment.)

If you have to use CLI command, you could use [Deploy ZIP file with Azure CLI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-sg/azure/app-service/deploy-zip#deploy-zip-file-with-azure-cli)